# What is the Blackberry API equivalent to Java's HashMap Collection?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, hashmap

Is there a collection which is similar to a Java map with a key and value?

Comment: Beware of the difference between Hashtable and HashMap. The Hashtable has synchronized methods and this might change the behaviour of your code.

Answer (score 1):

[Hashtable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html) would be the closest general purpose collection.  If you are working with primitive keys or keys and values, there are some variations that do a better job of preserving types, and can be a little more efficient too:

- IntHashtable
- IntIntHashtable
- IntLongHashtable
- LongHashtable
- LongIntHashtable